# Make javascript animated bar synchronously to animated percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, percentage

The problem I faced is I can't figure out how to make the animated bar synchronously to the
percentage I. Right now I looks OKE but when I change the value '43' to '100' the percentage counter goes to slow.

example code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".barInner").animate({
                    width: 43 + "%",
                    opacity: 1
                }, 2500 );

                var display = $('.barInner');
                var currentValue = 0;
                var nextValue    = 43;

                var diff         = nextValue - currentValue;
                var step         = ( 0 < diff ? 1 : -1 ); 

                for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(diff); ++i) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        currentValue += step
                        display.text(currentValue + "%");
                    }, 54 * i)   
                }
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vTKw7/

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: change the value on jsfiddle from 48 to 100.. You will see the effect that the counter has not the same 'count speed' as the bar.. counter needed to be finished at the same time as the bar animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't synchronize an `.animate()` and a `setTimeout()` the way you seem to want. Try using your `setTimeout` to control the width of the progress bar and display the percentage number at the same time.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var display = $('.barInner');
            var currentValue = 0;
            var nextValue = 100;
            var diff = nextValue - currentValue;
            var step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);

            for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(diff); ++i) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    currentValue += step;
                    display.text(currentValue + "%");
                    $(".barInner").css({
                        width: currentValue + "%",
                        opacity: 1
                    });
                }, 54 * i)
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/6TMWm/

Or, using `.stop().animate()` to smooth it out a little:

```
                    $(".barInner").stop().animate({
                        width: currentValue + "%",
                        opacity: 1
                    },50);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/6TMWm/1/